# Starting Hadoop DFS - no such file or directory in $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm setting up a single Hadoop node, but when running `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh` it prints that it cannot find `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs`. The file at that location exists though, and I can read it perfectly fine.

Log from the start-dfs.sh script:

```
root@hadoop:/opt/hadoop-2.7.3# sbin/start-dfs.sh
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-hadoop.out
localhost: nice: ‘$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-root-datanode-hadoop.out
localhost: nice: ‘$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs’: No such file or directory
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf
```

As far as I can tell all my path variables are set correctly (echo $HADOOP_HOME returns the correct directory).

Comment: Is `HADOOP_HOME` set for root user as well?

Comment: @Ambrish I set them all in /etc/environment and I'm running everything from root, so I think so.

Comment: And what is the value of `HADOOP_HOME`

Comment: @Ambrish The install directory, '/opt/hadoop-2.7.3'.

Answer (score 0):

Generally  `/etc/environment` file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.

It is not processed by shell script.

Please do set your environment variable in `.bashprofile` or `.bashrc` and start the hadoop processes.

Please refer the details about [environment variables.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables)

Comment: Hmm - moved the variables over to `.bashrc` and some of the errors have gone, but not the ones about `/bin/hdfs`:


`root@hadoop:/opt/hadoop-2.7.3# sbin/start-dfs.sh`

`Starting namenodes on [{ip}]`

`{ip}: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-hadoop.out`

`{ip}: nice: ‘$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs’: No such file or directory`

`localhost: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-root-datanode-hadoop.out`

`localhost: nice: ‘$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs’: No such file or directory`